# Woocommerce featured products at the top of the categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product, wordpress-featured-image

I'm trying to display featured items as the first products on the category pages.

I tried the solution here but it did nothing - [Woocommerce - Display Featured Products at top of Category Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278914/woocommerce-display-featured-products-at-top-of-category-page?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "_I tried the solution here but it did nothing_" **1)** It seems to work? **2)** Please read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello. Yes, I'll try again. Thanks for the advice